# Load own icon font in Vaadin

Tags: java, css, fonts, vaadin, vaadin7

I created an icon font, using [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) and tried following the instructions from Vaadin to [use an own font](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+font+icons)

My files are structured like this:

```
|VAADIN
+---themes
    +---my-theme
        +---fonts
            +---my-font-icons.ttf
            |---...
        |---addons.scss
        |---my-theme.scss
        |---styles.scss
```

In my `styles.scss` I have written following:

```
@import "addons.scss";
@import "my-theme.scss";
@include v-font(MyFontIcons, './fonts/my-font-icons');

.monitoring-theme {
  @include addons;
  @include my-theme;
}
```

But I'm not able to getting the font to work in Java.

```
public enum MyIconFont implements FontIcon {
    BASKET(0xe905), 
    BOOKMARK(0x6e);

    private static final String fontFamily = "MyFontIcons";
    private int codepoint;

    MyIconFont(int codepoint) {
        this.codepoint = codepoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMIMEType() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(FontIcon.class.getSimpleName() + " should not be used where a MIME type is needed.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFontFamily() {
        return fontFamily;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCodepoint() {
        return codepoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<span class=\"v-icon MyFontIcons\">&#x" + Integer.toHexString(codepoint) + ";</span>";
    }
```

**EDIT:** Using the developer console in Chrome it looks like the font files aren't even loaded.

The `.css` file is created through maven, using:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>
                com.my.PluginThemeCompiler
            </mainClass>
            <arguments>
                <argument>my-theme</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

The created .css file is located in the `my-theme` folder, but the theme is not included inside my vaadin application.

Is there any way to maybe load the font as a `ClassResource` and use the icons from there?

Comment: What happens? Does it load the ttf file from the URL or is that step failing?

Comment: When looking at the generated styles.css, does it link to your font and is the final class name correct?

Comment: Then there is no chance it will load anything. Look into the sass compiling phase of your project

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: Why do you include the font via `v-font(...)` and not via `@include font(...)` as shown in the wiki document you mention?

Comment: I read here, that they're practically the same: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/8614199 and it actually doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the v-font function serves files relative to the valo theme's font directory.

It should look something like:

```
@include v-font(MyFontIcons, '../../../../../my-theme/fonts/my-font-icons');
```